# Unable to open or uninstall Tableau Public 2020

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to open Tableau Public. It won't let me and says, "An administrator has blocked you from running this app". I tried uninstalling it. It won't let me do that either. Does anyone know why?[image]

Comment: Contact your corporate IT help desk. They might be blocking it.

Comment: This is my personal laptop. I am the administrator. I cannot run the app using "Run With Administrator"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. I downloaded the latest version and installed it this resolved the problem. I hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue(Windows 10), the problem was I have already installed tableau public and I want to install Tableau desktop in my pc but somehow I am neither able to uninstall tableau public nor able to install the new version of tableau desktop.

Below are the steps which I have followed and now it's working fine for me.

1. Go to C:\Windows\SysWOW64 and find gpedit.exe and run it (other than Windows 10 you can direct run gpedi.exe from windows+r means from the run menu)
2. Go to the specified path as shown in the image and Disable it.
   [image]
3. Restart the pc and try to re-install it again.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and I tried a couple of things regarding Windows and none of them work so, I wouldnt try again. I downloaded again Tableau, installed and it works... just like Amit said

Answer (score 0):

Update: I downloaded the latest version and it seemed to solve the issue.